# record audio in mp3 format (Android)

Tags: android, cordova

i have seen doc for **phonegap 2.1** and **phonegap 2.7 for android , to record audio in **phonegap 2.1*** it should be recorded as **.mp3 file** , and* in phonegap 2.7 it should be recorded as .amr file , my question is its possible
to record audio in phonegap 2.7 for android as mp3 not as amr? ????

as mentiond
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/cordova_media_media.md.html#media.startRecord
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/cordova_media_media.md.html#media.startRecord